# Function that returns a list of tuples.

Tags: python

Id like to write a procedure that returns a list of tuples. The kth element in each tuple corresponding to the sum of the kth elements of the tuples in the lists given as input.

A = [(1,2), (3,4)]
B = [(10,20), (30,40)]

will return

> [(11,22) , (33, 44)]

```
def sumtuple(A,B):
    ret = []
    for K in A:
        for L in B:
            ret.append(K[0] + L[0], K[1] + L[1])
return ret
```

There is some clear flaws with my attempt, it gives some undesirable results, for example it gives (13,24) in the answer. I can see why this is going wrong. But what i can't do is write some code that gives me the result i want.

I'm a novice, please be kind.

Comment: Are you only dealing with 2-tuples, or does it need to work for all tuple sizes?

Comment: I'm just concerned with pairs at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to loop over both lists at the same time:

```
def sumtuple(A,B):
    ret = []
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        ret.append((a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]))

    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
def sumtuple(A,B):
    ret = []
    for K in range(len(A)):
        ret.append(A[K][0] + B[K][0], A[K][1] + B[K][1])
    return ret
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it could help countless others.

Answer (score 0):

using `map` with `operator.add` and `zip_longest` to work for uneven length lists:

```
from operator import add 
from itertools import zip_longest

print([tuple(map(add, a, b)) for a,b in zip_longest(A,B,fillvalue=(0,0))])
[(11, 22), (33, 44)]
```

You won't lose data if one list is a different length:

```
A = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
B = [(10, 20), (30, 40),(10,12)]
print([tuple(map(add, a, b)) for a,b in zip_longest(A,B,fillvalue=(0,0))])
[(11, 22), (33, 44), (10, 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Made from your function :)

```
def sumtuple(A,B):
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        l=[]
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            l.append(A[i][j]+B[i][j])
        l=tuple(l)
        b.append(l)
    return b
```